# "The Batman" puzzle: rataalada.com

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, unsolved-mysteries

I just saw the movie and went home to check whether the website [www.rataalada.com](http://www.rataalada.com) actually exists or not, and surprisingly, it does! Judging by the news articles I found while searching, it's been made for promoting the movie. Let's see if we can decipher something from the website about the sequel.

Here is the screenshot of the text that comes before the page settles down:

[image]

I recognized 1939 in the first IP and confirmed that Batman first appeared in the 27th issue of Detective Comics (released in May 1939, i.e. 5/1939). I'm not sure what the corresponding text means here. Is that a reference too?

After this message, the screen has a [CLICK FOR REWARD] button followed by a LOADING whose percentage increases with time. When you click the button you get the following image, appropriately named, Its_Not_Over_Yet.jpg:

[image]

I'm not sure how to decipher this without a key, but maybe the background for the image could help.

Hoping to see some interesting answers for this one!

Comment: Slight correction: Detective Comics #27 has a cover date of May 1939 (5/1939).

Comment: You'd be well served in splitting the IP part into another question. I'll hold off answering until then

Comment: @PuzzlingFerret Why? What if that is just part of the puzzle? What if the corresponding texts refers to certain events in the issues?

Comment: @Rohinb97 what will you do if they aren't and none of the answers cover both separate riddles?

Comment: It's better to have one question with all the relevant info pertaining to the puzzle than two questions with the same information base. Let's see how this pans out first.

Comment: Also the source code of the page contains a small easter egg : `"egg":"Nice try. You won't find anything here."`

Answer (score 8):

> Using a [cypher](https://comicbook.com/movies/news/the-batman-trailer-symbols-decipher-the-riddler-codes-solved/) I found on comicbook.com and some filling in the gaps I translated the code to

> You think I'm finished but perhaps you don't know the full truth Every ending is a new beginning something is coming

> [image: update]

The webpage with the cypher also shows what was on the page (rataalada.com) before the film's release which was some other promotional images

[image: Batman GCPD drawings]

[image: Question mark sign]

Here is the up to date cypher. I added the letters that I got from filling in the gaps on top of the ones already given:

[image: cypher]

I still haven't seen J used in a code yet.

Comment: @Luke Could you please include the spoiler tags when required? It is `>!`

Answer (score 4):

I ran the first image through OCR software to capture the output of the [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute):

| Originating FQDN or IP | IP address | Comic book issue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POS-0-3-0-0-CR01.ARKHAM.GOTHAMDATA.NET | [27.05.19.39] | [Detective Comics Vol 1. #27](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_27) Published May 1939 |
| TBR2.N54GHTM.IP.GOTHAMISP2.NET | [01.03.19.40] | [Batman Vol 1. #1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_1) Published March 1940 |
| CR2.N54GTHM.IP.GOTHAMISP2.NET | [58.12.19.41] | [Detective Comics Vol 1. #58](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_58) Published December 1941 |
| CR2.GTHMX.IP.GOTHAMISP2.NET | [140.10.19.48] | [Detective Comics Vol 1. #140](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_140) Published October 1948 |
| CR1.GTHMX.IP.GOTHAMISP2.NET | [405.03.19.87] | [Batman Vol 1. #405](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_405) Published March 1987 |
| CR3.GTHMX.IP.GOTHAMISP3.NET | [16.04.19.43] | [Batman Issue 16](https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Issue_16) Published April 1943 |
| CORRECTIONS.ARKHAM.GOV | [258.10.19.74] | [Batman Vol 1. #258](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_258) published October 1974 |
| 03.04.20.22 | [03.04.20.22] | N/A release date of [The Batman](https://imdb.com/title/tt1877830/) |

In order these relate to Batman's first appearance, and then subsequent villains he's faces. In order:

> The Joker, Penguin, The Riddler, Harvey Dent, Joker (again), Two Face

These match the order previous films were released in.

The cipher image seems unrelated.

Comment: The sixth one (Batman Issue 16) is noted as the first appearance of Alfred Pennyworth, and the seventh (Vol. 1 #258) is noted as the first appearance of Arkham Asylum. This lines up with the first five issues also marking the first appearances of various characters.

Comment: What about Poison Ivy, Bane and Mr. Freeze, or are we just supposed to forget that movie.  Which isn't a horrible idea.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Could be wrong, but I've brightened up the image and rotated 180 degrees I believe there is a sort of mask... at least I see something to that nature, while wearing a suit. I have cropped the image to only show the area i see of interest...

[image: It's Not Over Yet]

also while messing with the values a bit, contrast and such, i got only certain parts of the cipher revealed, which reads "but Perhaps beginning something is coming" but I couldn't do much with it beyond that point.